# Getting issues while trying to generate Doctrine2 CRUD

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I trying to generate a simple Doctrine2 CRUD by running the task `php app/console doctrine:generate:crud` but I get this error just before it ends:

> [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]   The target-entity
>   ProductBundle\Entity\KList cannot be found in
>   'ProductBundle\Entity\ListHasProduct#list'.

Why it's looking for that if in my entity I have not relation to that entity? This is my entity code:

```
<?php

namespace Wuelto\BankRulesBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="bank_rules")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
 */
class BankRules {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BankBundle\Entity\NBank" )      
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="n_bank", referencedColumnName="id")   
     */
    protected $n_bank;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)      
     */
    protected $regex;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")      
     */
    protected $action;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $created;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @ORM\Column(name="modified", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $modified;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="deletedAt", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $deletedAt;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setRegex($regex) {
        $this->regex = $regex;
        return true;
    }

    public function getRegex() {
        return $this->regex;
    }

    public function setAction($action) {
        $this->action = $action;
    }

    public function getAction() {
        return $this->action;
    }

    public function setCreated($created) {
        $this->created = $created;
    }

    public function getCreated() {
        return $this->created;
    }

    public function setModified($modified) {
        $this->modified = $modified;
    }

    public function getModified() {
        return $this->modified;
    }

    public function getDeletedAt() {
        return $this->deletedAt;
    }

    public function setDeletedAt($deletedAt) {
        $this->deletedAt = $deletedAt;
    }

}
```

How I can solve this?

**UPDATE 1**

I fix the first error by fixing this at `ListHastProduct` entity:

```
/**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\KList", inversedBy="products" )
   * @ORM\JoinColumns(@ORM\JoinColumn(name="kuser", referencedColumnName="kuser"),
   *                  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="klist", referencedColumnName="name"))   
   */
  protected $list;
```

but now I get this other error:

> [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]   Single id is not allowed on
>   composite primary key in entity ShoppingBundle\Entity\BillDetail

Here is my `BillDetail` definition:

```
<?php

namespace ShoppingBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="bill_detail")
 */
class BillDetail {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="int",length=11)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ShoppingBundle\Entity\Transaction")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ktransaction", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $transaction;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="kuser", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CatalogBundle\Entity\KCatalog")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="kcatalog", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $catalog;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal")
     */
    protected $amount;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime")
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     */
    protected $created;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="modified", type="datetime")
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     */
    protected $modified;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setUser(\UserBundle\Entity\User $user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getUser() {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setCatalog(\CatalogBundle\Entity\KCatalog $catalog) {
        $this->catalog = $catalog;
    }

    public function getCatalog() {
        return $this->catalog;
    }

    public function setTransaction(\ShoppingBundle\Entity\Transaction $transaction) {
        $this->transaction = $transaction;
    }

    public function getTransaction() {
        return $this->transaction;
    }

    public function setAmount($amount) {
        $this->amount = $amount;
    }

    public function getAmount() {
        return $this->amount;
    }

    public function setStatus($status) {
        $this->status = $status;
    }

    public function getStatus() {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function setCreated($created) {
        $this->created = $created;
    }

    public function getCreated() {
        return $this->created;
    }

    public function setModified($modified) {
        $this->modified = $modified;
    }

    public function getModified() {
        return $this->modified;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can we have the code for `ProductBundle\Entity\ListHasProduct`?

Comment: @cheesemacfly see my edition, I fixed that error but now another appears

Comment: Can you paste your `BillDetail` entity?

Comment: @benatespina updated main post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException] Single id is not allowed on
>   composite primary key in entity ShoppingBundle\Entity\BillDetail

The `BillDetail` has a composite primary key by:

- ID
- User
- Transaction
- Catalog

So, there are 2 ways to avoid this error:

1. Remove the `@ORM\Id` annotation from the other attributes in order to take the ID as unique ID field
2. Trigger the CRUD queries with a composite key, for example, you generally could do this:

   ```
    // find by id
   $bill = em->find('ShoppingBundle\Entity\BillDetail', 3);
   ```

   According to your mapping,  you must do it by:

   ```
   // find by composite key
   $bill = em->find('ShoppingBundle\Entity\BillDetail', array(
       'id'=> $idRequested, 
       'user' => $userRequested, 
       'transaction' => $transactionRequested, 
       'catalog' => $catalogRequested 
   ));
   ```